# How to download a file from Databricks filesystem without using CLI?

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks

I saved a file from Databricks notebook as follows:

```
joblib.dump(rf, '/dbfs/FileStore/model.pkl', compress=9)
```

How can I download it to my local filesystem without using CLI?

I tried as follows:

```
https://westeurope.azuredatabricks.net/dbfs/FileStore/model.pkl?o=####
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself:

```
https://westeurope.azuredatabricks.net/files/model.pkl?o=####
```

More details can be found [here](https://docs.databricks.com/data/filestore.html).

Comment: It didnt work on amazon cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is that you start to write to s3 bucket as

```
df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true") \
  .save("s3://<your folder desired(exist or not)/file")
```

Now you can retrieve it with `aws s3 cp <your folder desired(exist or not)/file <local file path>`